# Is there a non-projective flat module over a local ring?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Is there a non-projective flat module over a local ring?
Here I assume the ring is commutative with unit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is flat over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, but not projective.

Comment: Well done! So is $k((x))$ over $k[[x]]$...

Comment: So is the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion of any non-Artinian local ring.

Answer (score 6):

It is related to Bass' theorem. Flat modules are projective iff the ring is perfect. $p$-adic integers or formal power series are examples of local rings which are not perfect and have nonprojective flat modules.

Comment: But we can also make a slightly positive statement.  Every local ring is semiperfect, and every finitely generated flat module over a semiperfect ring is projective.  Moreover, since projective modules over a local ring are free, we see that every finitely generated flat module over a local ring is free.

Comment: For those, who -- like me -- didn't know what a perfect ring was, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring.